# Generate Python Documentation from .pyi stub

Tags: python-3.x, documentation-generation, pyo3

I Have a Pyo3 project written in rust where I'm generating a python package.  To get IDE typings, I've created a .pyi stub, with relevant docstrings.

However, I notice that the docstrings on the actual python objects are empty.  This isn't a huge deal to me on it's own, but it does mean that traditional api docgen tools such as pdoc won't work.

Fundamentally, I would like to be able to use a docgen tool to automatically generate api docs for this pyo3 project that I can host on a site.

I have a hacky script that can read in the .pyi stub as a regular python file, then update doc fields on the corresponding python object which allows for things like pdoc to read in some info.  However, I can't read in/copy over type annotations, which makes it only a partial solution.